# Flipper + React Native - can I debug JavaScript?

Tags: react-native

I feel stupid that I'm asking that but - Is it possible to debug JavaScript (setting breakpoints, see variables values) with Flipper in a React Native environment?

Answer (score 6):

Today, it is only possible to debug JavaScript with Flipper if you use Hermes.

[image]

So, without Hermes is not possible to add breakpoint, show variable values or debug line by line.